# How to create Lines connecting two points in R

Tags: r, graphics, visualization, lines

Is there any way to create lines in R connecting two points?
I am aware of lines(), function, but it creates line segment what I am looking for is an infinite length line.

Comment: Maybe `abline`? https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/abline.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I was not looking for abline. I like to move parametrically in vector space rather than a coordinate geometry           (y=mx+c) solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an example of Martha's suggestion:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- runif(2)
y <- runif(2)

# function
segmentInf <- function(xs, ys){
  fit <- lm(ys~xs)
  abline(fit)
}

plot(x,y)
segmentInf(x,y)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I believe creating a self-defined function like this is the best solution. Probably R does not have any such predefined function.

Comment: I have up voted but my level is 11 right now. Once I reach 15 the vote will be applicable.

Answer (score 4):

```
#define x and y values for the two points
x <- rnorm(2)
y <- rnorm(2)
slope <- diff(y)/diff(x)
intercept <- y[1]-slope*x[1]
plot(x, y)
abline(intercept, slope, col="red")
# repeat the above as many times as you like to satisfy yourself
```

Answer (score 1):

Use segment() function.

```
#example    
x1 <- stats::runif(5)
x2 <- stats::runif(5)+2
y <- stats::rnorm(10)


plot(c(x1,x2), y)


segments(x1, y[1:5], x2, y[6:10], col= 'blue')
```

Comment: Thanks, but i was not looking for segments.

Comment: why you dont want segments ?